# zfs force import multiple VMS (IDs) and now can't find VM but it's not missing according to zfs?

Tags: zfsonlinux, zpool, openzfs

I'm completely new to ZFS. Today, I did something stupid and caused a problem where I need to recover my entire OS. On a live OS I'm using to recover my machine, I need to mount my ZFS volumes for data transfer. I did the following:

```
root@kubuntu:/media/kubuntu/backup3-1tb/recovery# zpool import
   pool: nas-2-mirror
     id: 11643301469609613604
  state: ONLINE
status: The pool was last accessed by another system.
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier and
        the '-f' flag.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-EY
 config:

        nas-2-mirror                                               ONLINE
          mirror-0                                                 ONLINE
            usb-SanDisk_Extreme_55AE_32333135314D343031353938-0:0  ONLINE
            usb-SanDisk_Extreme_55AE_32333135325A343030313338-0:0  ONLINE

   pool: nas-1-mirror
     id: 10379406262813511849
  state: ONLINE
status: The pool was last accessed by another system.
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier and
        the '-f' flag.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-EY
 config:

        nas-1-mirror                                               ONLINE
          mirror-0                                                 ONLINE
            usb-SanDisk_Extreme_55AE_32333135314D343031323130-0:0  ONLINE
            usb-SanDisk_Extreme_55AE_323331363748343030333133-0:0  ONLINE
root@kubuntu:/media/kubuntu/backup3-1tb/recovery# zpool import -f 
   pool: nas-2-mirror
     id: 11643301469609613604
  state: ONLINE
status: The pool was last accessed by another system.
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier and
        the '-f' flag.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-EY
 config:

        nas-2-mirror                                               ONLINE
          mirror-0                                                 ONLINE
            usb-SanDisk_Extreme_55AE_32333135314D343031353938-0:0  ONLINE
            usb-SanDisk_Extreme_55AE_32333135325A343030313338-0:0  ONLINE

   pool: nas-1-mirror
     id: 10379406262813511849
  state: ONLINE
status: The pool was last accessed by another system.
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier and
        the '-f' flag.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-EY
 config:

        nas-1-mirror                                               ONLINE
          mirror-0                                                 ONLINE
            usb-SanDisk_Extreme_55AE_32333135314D343031323130-0:0  ONLINE
            usb-SanDisk_Extreme_55AE_323331363748343030333133-0:0  ONLINE
root@kubuntu:/media/kubuntu/backup3-1tb/recovery# zpool import -f 11643301469609613604 10379406262813511849
cannot import '10379406262813511849': name must begin with a letter
root@kubuntu:/media/kubuntu/backup3-1tb/recovery# zpool import -f nas-1-mirror nas-2-mirror  <<<==== THIS
```

Now `nas-2-mirror` is fine!

```
root@kubuntu:~# zpool status
  pool: nas-2-mirror
 state: ONLINE
config:

        NAME                                                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        nas-2-mirror                                               ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                                                 ONLINE       0     0     0
            usb-SanDisk_Extreme_55AE_32333135314D343031323130-0:0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            usb-SanDisk_Extreme_55AE_323331363748343030333133-0:0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

However, `nas-1-mirror` is nowhere to be found. I tried to re-import it using its ID:

```
root@kubuntu:~# zpool import -f 10379406262813511849
cannot import '10379406262813511849': a pool with that name already exists
use the form 'zpool import <pool | id> <newpool>' to give it a new name

root@kubuntu:~# zpool list
NAME           SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
nas-2-mirror  1.81T  40.1G  1.77T        -         -     0%     2%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```

I thought maybe I borked the name of the volume by importing two volumes at once, so I took the help advice from the import above and tried re-naming the volume

```
root@kubuntu:~# zpool import -f 10379406262813511849 nas-1-mirror
cannot import '10379406262813511849': no such pool available
```

I thought maybe I could attempt to just mount it?

```
root@kubuntu:~# zfs mount nas-1-mirror
cannot open 'nas-1-mirror': dataset does not exist

root@kubuntu:~# zfs list -o name,canmount,mountpoint
NAME          CANMOUNT  MOUNTPOINT
nas-2-mirror  on        /nas/nas-media
```

I'm a little concerned. Anyone have anything else I can try?

**EDIT**

Ah hah! I see what I did. My import renamed the ID to the ID used in the second param in my arguments there.

```
root@kubuntu:~# zpool list -o guid nas-2-mirror
 GUID
10379406262813511849
```

So I need to figure out how to undo this.

https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/renaming-zfs-pool-via-zpool-import-mypool-newpoolname.46300/ is relevant (second question), but there is no clear answer on how to fix the problem. I attempted to use `zpool import -fa` but I get:

```
root@kubuntu:~# zpool import -fa
cannot import 'nas-2-mirror': pool already exists
```

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I can't try this yet, but maybe: https://illumos.org/books/zfs-admin/gavwn.html

section: `4.1.1. Using Disks in a ZFS Storage Pool`

> If you inadvertently change both the path and the ID of the device, then export and re-import the pool in order to use it.

When I can, I'll try that suggestion and see where that gets me. I'll post accordingly.

I also see that `zfs` exposes a `rename` command, so I'll try this too:

```
zfs rename 10379406262813511849 nas-1-mirror
```

after I'm done with operation I'm working. I don't want to inadvertently mess with anything.

Answer (score 0):

First note that for anyone who uses this needs to make sure they are working safely with their volumes. In my case, I was in a running "live" Ubuntu session.

OK! I was able to fix this quite simply. The steps I had to take were:

1. export the mounted pool

`root@kubuntu:/# zpool export nas-2-mirror`

2. import the erroneously imported UID to the old pool name (effectively renaming it back to what it was before I messed up...)

`root@kubuntu:/# zpool import 10379406262813511849 nas-1-mirror`

3. import the original nas-2-mirror (forcefully and by ID because it was inadvertently lost in my OS snafu (mentioned earlier) and...

```
root@kubuntu:/# zpool import 11643301469609613604 nas-2-mirror
cannot import 'nas-2-mirror': pool was previously in use from another system.
Last accessed by your-linux-host (hostid=44ddb8ce) at Fri Oct  6 13:52:02 2023
The pool can be imported, use 'zpool import -f' to import the pool.
root@kubuntu:/# zpool import -f 11643301469609613604 nas-2-mirror
```

Lastly, check that everything is OK:

```
root@kubuntu:/# zpool list
NAME           SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
nas-1-mirror  1.81T   234G  1.58T        -         -     0%    12%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
nas-2-mirror  1.81T  35.7G  1.78T        -         -     0%     1%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```